# Mysql speed: table with many columns or 2 tables using a join

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I tried searching for this but I could not find anything about this but design choices.

So my question is like the title. What is faster? Create 1 table with many columns or create 2 or 3 (for many to many) tables with join(s).

I like the idea of have multiple tables so the data is separated. Mostly for many to many like data. But my friend told me having 5 columns with boolean is just fine. But I like the idea of have a table with the settings and then a table between with user.id and setting.id. But my question is also, does it have a impact on the query?

example:

```
Users
- id
- Email
- SettingA
- SettingB
- SettingC
```

OR example:

```
Uers
- id
- email
Users_Settings
- user_id
- setting_id
Settings
- id
- someSettingsValue
```

What woult be faster for Mysql to query the data? (retrieving settings for user)

Comment: Edit your question and show an example of your schemas. You should understand normalization, and represent your data in the DB as it really is. If it has one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, then build it using multiple tables.

Comment: In general, sql hates columns and loves rows. Does that help?

Comment: Regarding speed, no way to answer with so little info. Will you have a few records or billions? Are you talking about 10 columns or a few hundred?

Comment: Added extra info, is this the info you needed or you need anything else?

Comment: If two tables have the same `PRIMARY KEY`, it is almost always better to have a single table.

Answer (score 0):

not at all.. Only joins between 2 r 3 will take time compared to single table fields.

Comment: wrong suggestion.. if you did this then it wont be normalized

Comment: @Gaj I read a article, It shows as a sub query is 260x faster than left join 
And how can my suggestion goes wrong <https://crate.io/a/sql-subquery-vs-left-join/>

Comment: Left join is costlier than sub query. But if you are not normalized then there is lot of possibilities of duplication. Also i couldn't understand why are talking about left join and subquery here.. we have to use those features in correct place both are useful.

Answer (score 0):

It's not about preferring single table with many columns or preferring multiple tables. It's about Normalization.

According to your provided schema, if all users will always have three settings, i.e. Setting A, B and C, then it's better to create single table with these three columns for settings.

```
users table:
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | Email    | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | SettingA | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | SettingB | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | SettingC | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

But if any of the setting is saved is null, then better is to create separate table for settings and then a pivot table for maintaining users' settings without primary key.

```
users table:
    +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | Email | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

settings table:
    +---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field         | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id            | int(11)    | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | setting_value | tinyint(1) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    +---------------+------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

setting_user pivot table:
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
    | setting_id | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    | user_id    | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
    +------------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Where setting_user is the pivot table.

One more thing is considered when creating schema, that, will there be always three settings, or will there be more in future, when application is expanded!

Comment: Please read my question. Its not about design choices, this question is about performance!

Comment: Regarding performance joins are a bit slower, so in this case, a single table is preferred keeping in mind that, only fewer columns for settings will be there i.e. 3 in your case.